# Django session not saved

Tags: django, django-sessions

I'm using session to store variables

```
def remotelogin(request):
.......
request.session['remote_auth_url'] = auth_url
request.session['remote_u_token'] = unscoped_token.id
request.session['remote_projects'] = projects
request.session['remote_n_url'] = n_url
request.session['remote_dc'] = datacenter_id
return redirect('project:networks', datacenter_id)
```

My urls.py dispatch to my class based views

```
class NetworkView(tables.DataTableView):
table_class = NetworksDCTable
template_name = 'project/networks.html'


def get_data(self):
    request = self.request
    remote_networks = list()

    remote_auth_url = request.session.get('remote_auth_url')
    remote_unscoped_token = request.session.get('remote_u_token')
    projects = request.session.get('remote_projects')
    remote_dc = request.session.get('remote_dc')

    keystone_client = utils.get_keystone_client()
    for p in projects:
```

But when I want to get `request.session.get('remote_projects')` I have a key error because every variables stored in my session doesn't exist anymore.
I have checked with a `print(request.sessions.keys())` and keys `remote_auth_url`, `remote_u_token`, `remote_projects` and the others stored in my previous method disapears. 
Does anyone have a idea?

Comment: What are you using for sessions? Have you enabled the right settings? https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/sessions/#module-django.contrib.sessions

Comment: where is `remotelogin` function ?

Comment: This is my settings :
SESSION_ENGINE = 'django.contrib.sessions.backends.signed_cookies'
SESSION_SAVE_EVERY_REQUEST = True
SESSION_COOKIE_HTTPONLY = True
SESSION_EXPIRE_AT_BROWSER_CLOSE = True
SESSION_COOKIE_SECURE = False
SESSION_TIMEOUT = 1800
remotelogin is in views.py file as my class NetworkView